# How to use Import[] to grab text displayed on a Twitter page for a non-existent username?

Tags: import, social-media

Let's say `http://www.foo.bar/?domain=wibble` returns a search page on the word "wibble" provided by an engine with the frontdoor address `www.foo.bar`, and you have a variable called `searchvar` that you want to search on.

You can assign the resulting search page to variable `searchresult` like this:

```
searchresult = Import[StringJoin[{"http://www.foo.bar/?domain=", searchvar}], "HTML"];
```

And then you can look in searchresult for whatever it is that you are trying to find.

I am trying to do this to find whether a given string has been registered as a Twitter username.

When you browse to, say, `https://twitter.com/aosododof`, you get a page that contains the words "This account doesn't exist", and then you can go ahead and register that name if you wish.

However, although the words "This account doesn't exist" are on my screen I am not seeing them in the source for the page, and therefore they are not being returned to `Import[]`.

So my question is: how can I use `Import[]` to grab the text from a page such as `https://twitter.com/aosododof` that includes the words "doesn't exist" so that I can then log that name as available?

I have a few thousand that I would like to look up, so this needs to be automated.

Answer (score 5):

When possible, avoid parsing of websites to get information. As you have discovered, this can lead to many issues (such as content not being visible in a "dumb" download), and is very prone to breaking if anything about the website changes. Instead, many websites offer APIs for other services to communicate with them. These APIs are well-defined and stable ways of getting information into and out of those websites. In the case of Twitter, the API documentation can be found [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api).

In this particular case, Mathematica already has API access built into [`ServiceConnect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ServiceConnect.html), see the [Twitter Service Connection](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/Twitter.html):

```
twitter = ServiceConnect["Twitter"]
(* ServiceObject["Twitter", "ID" -> "connection-XXXXXXXXXXXX"] *)

twitter["UserData", "Username" -> "WolframResearch"]
(* {<|"ID" -> 22659609, "ScreenName" -> "WolframResearch", 
  "Name" -> "Wolfram", "Location" -> Missing["NotAvailable"], 
  "FavouritesCount" -> 3455, "FollowersCount" -> 54999, 
  "FriendsCount" -> 371, "TweetsCount" -> 8230, 
  "CreationDate" -> 
   DateObject[{2009, 3, 3, 18, 56, 15}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 0.]|>} *)
```

Asking for a non-existant user gives an error:

```
twitter["UserData", "Username" -> "WolframResearch2"]
(* ServiceExecute::nouser: No user matches for specified terms. *)
(* ServiceObject["Twitter", "ID" -> "connection-XXXXXXXXXXXX"]["UserData", 
 "Username" -> "WolframResearch2"] *)
```

We can now pack it up into a function:

```
twitterUserExistsQ[user_] := 
 Quiet@Check[twitter["UserData", "Username" -> user]; True, False]

twitterUserExistsQ["WolframResearch"]
(* True *)

twitterUserExistsQ["WolframResearch2"]
(* False *)
```

Comment: Beautiful! Many thanks for this. Is there a way to make it count a twittername as existent not only when it is operative but also when it has been suspended, e.g. a name such as "boiddy"?

Comment: Checking on "Friends" rather than on "Username" seems to do the job, because suspended status, which counts as existence for "Username", appears to count as non-existence for "Friends".  (I am still testing this and therefore not wholly certain.)